# Symmetry of an equilateral triangle

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry

I am currently studying "Elements of Abstract Algebra" by Allan Clark. In one of the exercises(26η) of the book he asks: "Show that a symmetry of an equilateral triangle ABC is completely determined by the way it transforms the vertices."

I do not understand what exactly I need to show.

Thanks , in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to proof two things:

1) given two symmetries $f,g$ of the triangle $ABC$, **if** $f(A)=g(A)$, $f(B)=g(B)$, and $f(C)=g(C)$, **then** $f$ and $g$ are the same symmetry.

and

2) **given** any permutation of the vertices $A,B,C$ there **exists** a symmetry of the triangle that permutes the vertices in the given way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question for further clarification: "Isn't it "1)" is directly obvious? What I mean is that, for each element in the domain f and g map them to same element.Thus, this two functions(symmetries) are equal , by definition.

Comment: No, two functions which are not symmetries can be equal on vertices but not on the interior of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that **a symmetry that has $3$ non-linear fixed points is the identity**

In order to do that name $A,B,C$ these points and show that the symmetry will preserve the sides of the triangle $ABC$.Then for an arbitrary point $M$ one of the lines $AM,BM,CM$ will have a common point with a side of the triangle,so this line will also be preserved by the symmetry,hence $f(M)=M$

Now for any two symmetries $f,g$ that are:$f(A)=g(A),f(B)=g(B),f(C)=g(C)$ for the $f\circ g^{-1}$ you will have the above property so $f\circ g^{-1}=id\Rightarrow f=g$